# Is it possible to get a draw in 1v1?

Tags: overwatch

In the 1v1 arcade mode, what happens when both players die at the same time?  Is it even possible for the players to die at the "same time"?  If it is possible, how is it counted in terms of the best of nine rounds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible for both players to die simultaneously, which results in a draw for the round.  It's also possible for time to run out on the round, resulting in a draw.  However, these rounds aren't counted towards the maximum nine rounds per match.  In fact, don't even think of it as a best of nine, think of it as first to five points.  If the match is tied 4 to 4, and as Mei (other characters are possible too) you both land an icicle killing blow, the round won't be counted, and you'll go into a new match point round with a new character.  The round that ended in a draw won't even show up in the end game summary.

Comment: I've had a draw in a 3v3 where dva and ana where the last remaining and neither could kill the other. Time expired and the round ended in a draw and also didn't show up in the summary or give either team a point.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was a time limit or not, as that never happened to me.  I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @MBraedley Yeah, after a couple minutes, both teams gain infrasight and a 60 second countdown to a draw starts.

Comment: @Unionhawk: I knew about the infrasight (that happened a couple time to me tonight), but I didn't realize a draw happened shortly after that.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill How did you get a draw with D.Va? The first person to defense matrix loses, other than that just hold primary fire.

Comment: @KizTrap he's talking in a 3v3, which also applies to duels in that situation.

Comment: Here's a video of a draw occurring in a Reinhardt vs Reinhardt match: https://gfycat.com/PeskySimplisticGermanshepherd

Comment: @Karlyr Oh. That'll teach me to skim read, I guess :P Does the 3v3 have no Lucio/Mercy restriction like the 1v1? Curious how Mercy's res would work in that sitch

Comment: @KizTrap No there isn't. The restriction in duels was likely placed to dodge the everlasting healing of Mercy's passive health gain and Lucio's healing song. Both characters doesn't have enough damage to get through the healing (unless taking the damage on purpose). In 3v3, the likelyhood of ending on such a duel is really low and would deserve a draw imo.

Comment: @Karlyr Fair enough. I should really give 3v3 a try.